# Replace Nested For Loops... or not

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

I have a script that loops through a series of four (or less) characters strings.  For example:

```
aaaa
aaab
aaac
aaad
```

If have been able to implement it with nested for loops like so:

```
chars = string.digits + string.uppercase + string.lowercase

for a in chars:
    print '%s' % a   
    for b in chars:
        print '%s%s' % (a, b)
        for c in chars:
            print '%s%s%s' % (a, b, c)
            for d in chars:
                print '%s%s%s%s' % (a, b, c, d)
```

Is this sort of loop nesting a bad thing, and if so, what would be a better way of accomplishing what I am doing?

Comment: try thinking out a better algorithm than brute force. Maybe recursion or divide and conquer

Comment: @Perpetual, it seems to me that since you have to generate ALL possibilities, it makes little difference whether it's brute force or not. Non-brute-force algo's are good when you can minimize what you need, but I don't think that's the case here. Recursion gets you smaller sourcecode, but that's it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
import string
import itertools

chars = string.digits + string.letters
MAX_CHARS = 4
for nletters in range(MAX_CHARS):
    for word in itertools.product(chars, repeat=nletters + 1):
        print (''.join(word))
```

That'll print all **`15018570`** words you're looking for. If you want more/less words just change the `MAX_CHARS` variable. It will still have just two `for`s for any number of chars, and you don't have to repeat yourself.  And is pretty readable. .

Comment: Syntax Error... you're missing a colon.

Comment: This should mention that it requires python 2.6, but otherwise it's the solution I was going to post. :)

Comment: "is pretty readable"? - I still think the original is more understandable but then I'm a dinosaur and I've never seen itertools, so I won't -1 you :-).

Comment: Can you explain why it is satisfies "no nested for's" when I see two apparently nested copies of the keyword?

Comment: Actually I thought I'd do a performance check to see how much faster itertools is. The results were surprising - under Python 2.6.1 (Windows), itertools is MUCH slower (2.16 as opposed to 0.45 time.clock() units). Without output and run five times each within the script to remove startup time.

Comment: Retract that last benchmark statement (it was a dodgy benchmark :-). Original question took 2.84 units, optimized (see my answer below) took 2.25 and itertools took 2.27. So itertools seems slightly slower but probably not enough to worry about.

Comment: @Nick: If you need it in python < 2.6 there is an implementation of product() here: http://docs.python.org/library/itertools#itertools.product

Comment: @Jonathan: Because you can use 20, 30, 40 chars, how many you want, without inserting more fors. I changed the text to better reflect what I mean. It could be written to use a single for too, using itertools.chain.from_iterable().

Comment: string.ascii_letters != (string.lowercase + string.uppercase). `lowercase`, `uppercase` are locale-dependant.

Comment: I never knew about itertools.product, or at least had never looked into it that much. This a great answer.

Comment: (string.lowercase + string.uppercase) == string.letters

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to submit my answer as the most readable and least scalable :)

```
import string
chars = [''] + list(string.lowercase)

strings = (a+b+c+d for a in chars
                   for b in chars
                   for c in chars
                   for d in chars)

for string in strings:
    print string
```

EDIT: Actually, this is incorrect, as it will produce duplicates of all strings of length<4.  Removing the empty string from the `chars` array would just produce 4-char strings.

Normally I'd delete this answer, but I still kinda like it if you need to generate strings of the same length.

Comment: I like it... it's like an invisible time bomb.

Comment: It covers all words, note the empty string in the list of "characters".

Comment: You solution is much more readable but it produces different output: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/482146/replace-nested-for-loops-or-not#482990

Comment: Yup, it will produce duplicates of every string of length<4.  I'll make a note.

Answer (score 4):

Write for the programmer first - the computer second.
If it's clear and obvious to understand then its correct.

If speed matters AND the compiler doesn't optimise it anyway AND if you measure it AND it is the problem - then think of a faster cleverer way!

Comment: Not every programmer is a theoretician.  Most of us have work to get done by a certain date and are not bound by the cpu.  In this case, mgb is correct and you should write for the programmer.  The OP's algo is not that, but it doesn't mean that mgb is wrong, perhaps not helpful though.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's a bad thing, provided you understand (and document :-) it. I don't doubt there may be a more pythonic way or clever solution (with lambdas or whatnot) but I've always favored readability over cleverness.

Since you have to generate all possibilities of 1-, 2-, 3- and 4-character "words", this method is as good as any. I'm not sure how long it would take since you're effectively generating (very roughly) 14 million lines of output (but probably every solution would have that problem).

Pre-calculating the common prefixes may provide a speed boost but you'd be better off measuring it to check (**always** check, **never** assume):

```
chars = string.digits + string.uppercase + string.lowercase
for a in chars:
    print a
    for b in chars:
        ab = '%s%s' % (a, b)
        print ab
        for c in chars:
            abc = '%s%s' % (ab, c)
            print abc
            for d in chars:
                print '%s%s' % (abc, d)
```

EDIT: I actually did some benchmarks (with Windows-Python 2.6.1) - this version takes about 2.25 time units compared to the original 2.84 so it's 26% faster. I think that might warrant its use (again, as long as it's documented clearly what it's trying to achieve).

Comment: You can save quite some time by always doing a simple `a+b` instead of `'%s%s' % (a, b)`

Answer (score 2):

[@nosklo's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/482146/replace-nested-for-loops-or-not#482192) and [@Triptych's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/482146/replace-nested-for-loops-or-not#482217) solutions produce different results:

```
>>> list(map(''.join, itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.product("ab", 
...     repeat=r) for r in range(4)))) # @nosklo's
```

```
['', 'a', 'b', 'aa', 'ab', 'ba', 'bb', 'aaa', 'aab', 'aba', 'abb', 'baa', 
 'bab', 'bba', 'bbb']
```

```
>>> ab = ['']+list("ab")
>>> list(map(''.join, (a+b+c for a in ab for b in ab for c in ab)))
```

```
['', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'aa', 'ab', 'b', 'ba', 'bb', 'a', 'aa', 'ab', 'aa', 
 'aaa', 'aab', 'ab', 'aba', 'abb', 'b', 'ba', 'bb', 'ba', 'baa', 'bab', 
 'bb',  'bba', 'bbb']
```

Here's modified @Triptych's solution that produce the same output as the @nosklo's one:

```
>>> ab = "ab"
>>> list(map(''.join, itertools.chain([''], ab, (a+b for a in ab for b in ab),
...     (a+b+c for a in ab for b in ab for c in ab))))
```

```
['', 'a', 'b', 'aa', 'ab', 'ba', 'bb', 'aaa', 'aab', 'aba', 'abb', 'baa', 
 'bab', 'bba', 'bbb']
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many algorithms for generating every permutation of a set.  What you want here is a related problem, but not directly analagous.  [Suggested Reading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Algorithms_to_generate_permutations)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't exactly answer the question, but this would return the `n`th combination for the given maximum length and characters in the alphabet to use:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def nth_combination(n, maxlen=4, alphabet='abc'):
    """
    >>> print ','.join(nth_combination(n, 1, 'abc') for n in range(3))
    a,b,c
    >>> print ','.join(nth_combination(n, 2, 'abc') for n in range(12))
    a,aa,ab,ac,b,ba,bb,bc,c,ca,cb,cc
    >>> import string ; alphabet = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
    >>> print ','.join(nth_combination(n, 4, alphabet) for n in range(16))
    a,aa,aaa,aaaa,aaab,aaac,aaad,aaae,aaaf,aaag,aaah,aaai,aaaj,aaak,aaal,aaam
    >>> print ','.join(nth_combination(n, 4, alphabet)
    ...                for n in range(0, 14000000, 10**6))
    a,emiL,iyro,mKz2,qWIF,u8Ri,zk0U,Dxav,HJi9,LVrM,P7Ap,UjJ1,YvSE,2H1h
    """
    if maxlen == 1:
        return alphabet[n]
    offset, next_n = divmod(n, 1 + len(alphabet)**(maxlen-1))
    if next_n == 0:
        return alphabet[offset]
    return alphabet[offset] + nth_combination(next_n-1, maxlen-1, alphabet)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from doctest import testmod
    testmod()
```

This of course makes sense only if you need random access to the set of combinations instead of always iterating through them all.

If `maxlen` is high, some speed optimization could be achieved e.g. by getting rid of string concatenation and re-calculating the length of `alphabet` and `maxlen-1` at each level of the recursion. A non-recursive approach might make sense, too.