# Make a 3D array where each item references the current row, column and item in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to make a 3D-array where each element references the current row, column and item. So if I have `x=[0,1]`, `y=[0,1,2]` and `item=['a','b']`, I wish the output to be

```
arr = [ [ [00a, 10a], [01a, 11a], [02a, 12a] ], 
[ [00b, 10b], [01b, 11b], [02b, 12b] ]]
```

I know that this can be easily done with a triple loop as such

```
for i in range(len(x)):
  for j in range(len(y)):
    for it in range(len(item)):
      arr[i,j,it] = str(i)+str(j)+it
```

but is there a more elegant way to do it, for example with some numpy command? Thanks!

Comment: I do not know if numpy has such a command, but you could also use list comprehension if you want a better performance.

Comment: What are you trying to improve?

Comment: @wwii I want to know if there is an easier way of doing this, preferable something that can be done with less lines.

Comment: @DavidDuran How would I use list comprehension?

Comment: @MrNobody33 has given you the answer using list comprehension

Comment: related: [Replace Nested For Loops… or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/482146/replace-nested-for-loops-or-not), [Single Line Nested For Loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17006641/single-line-nested-for-loops). - when you searched for solutions for replacing nested for loops why were none of the search results acceptable.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use list comprehension:

```
arr=[[[f'{i}{j}{k}' for k in item]for j in y]for i in x]
```

Output:

```
arr
[[['00a', '00b'], ['01a', '01b'], ['02a', '02b']],
 [['10a', '10b'], ['11a', '11b'], ['12a', '12b']]]
```

---

Antoher option using `itertools` and `numpy`:

```
import itertools 
import numpy as np
prod=itertools.product(x,y,item)
prod=list(map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}{x[1]}{x[2]}',prod))
np.array(prod).reshape(len(x),len(y),len(item))
```

Output:

```
array([[['00a', '00b'],
        ['01a', '01b'],
        ['02a', '02b']],

       [['10a', '10b'],
        ['11a', '11b'],
        ['12a', '12b']]], dtype='<U3')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution without loops using numpy:

```
import numpy as np

x=np.array([0,1]).astype(str)
y=np.array([0,1,2]).astype(str)
items=np.array(['a','b'])


temp= np.core.defchararray.add(y[:,np.newaxis], items)
result = np.core.defchararray.add(x[:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis], temp)

print(result)
```

**output:**

```
[[['00a' '00b']
  ['01a' '01b']
  ['02a' '02b']]

 [['10a' '10b']
  ['11a' '11b']
  ['12a' '12b']]]
```

Comment: In my experience `defchararray` functions are not fast.  They still use python string methods, one element at a time.